# Why is my screen width more that 100%?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out why is it when I set my header to width 100% it goes passed the right side 2%. I've looked all over and all the fixes seem insufficient. I've set the body and the html padding and margins to 0 and still when it set the header to 100% is sticks off to the right 2% so I have to set the header to 98% so it's fully from left to right. Here is a jsfiddle to show what I mean.

Side problem(I can make a new post of this) - The nav isn't inside the header for some reason...(If i remove the floats then it centers)

Change line 18 in the css code.

https://jsfiddle.net/RVKuzmik/zbgsmdzk/

```
code
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*Navigation bar*/

header {
  width: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1%;
  color: black;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Bob">
    <!--I have a normalize.css here-->
    <!--CSS STYLE SHEET HERE-->
    <title>HomeC</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a id="testbtn" href="test.php">test</a></li>
          <li><a id="testtwobtn" href="testtwo.php">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Regarding your second point, the header element can only contain h1, h2, etc. elements

Comment: @jhpratt Alright, cool, thanks!

Comment: @jhpratt If I remove the floats then it centers in the header.

Comment: When you have your `header` at 100%, did you have padding as well?

Comment: @disinfor You're right! I had the overall padding set and it was messing with the width! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, CSS defines an element's `width` as the width of the content only, before any border or padding is applied. Most users find this unwieldy as like in your situation, it's good to know the total width of the element with the padding and border.

The fix for this is the `box-sizing` property, set to `border-box`. For any project I work on, I set this as the default for any element like so:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Docs: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Once you've got that, you can do:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

So you can change the padding of the header to whatever you like, and you know the width will stay at 100% regardless.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `*{ box-sizing: border-box;}`

This is often called "universal box-sizing", and it's a good way to work! The (literal) width you set is the width you get, without having to perform mental math and manage the complexity that comes from widths that come from multiple properties.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zbgsmdzk/6/

Answer (score -2):

I got it thanks to @disinfor

The problem was that I had set the header padding at 1% when all I need was padding-top at 1%.

Thanks!